# How to find the closest elements of average in C?

Tags: arrays, c

**Hi**, how can I find the closest number of average in this array?
**Idk how to do this.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int arraysum();
int main()
{
    int n, A[100], i, b, sum;
    float average;
    printf("Enter number of elements in array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    printf("Numbers of this array: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        
    
    average=arraysum(A, sum, i, n)/n;
    printf("\nAverage is: %.2f", average);       
}
int arraysum(int A[], int sum, int i, int n)
{
    sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        sum+=A[i];
    return sum; 
}
```

**Thanks in advance, guys!**
:D

Comment: Instead of duplicating meaningless text, provide more details of the problem. Such as the definition of the "closest number of average".

Comment: Do you want to find the number in the array that is closest to the average? Or the number of such numbers (can be 1 or more)?

Comment: Average calculation is amiss as integer division truncates toward zero.  The missing subsequent search for the closest element should use a more precise average.

Comment: @kol Yes, I want to find the number in the array, that is closest to the average.

Comment: The `arraysum` function only needs two parameters: the array (`int A[]`) and the number of elements in the array (`int n`). The other two (`int sum` and `int i`) should be removed from the parameter list, and declared as local variables.

Comment: Have any of the comments/answers addressed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

After finding the average, iterate looking for closest.

```
// Pseudo code
average=arraysum(A, sum, i, n)/n;
best = element 0
for (each element in the array [1...n-1])
  if (|A[i] - average| < |A[best] - average|) 
    best = i
```

To cope with an average than is not exactly an integer and not use unnecessary floating point math ...

```
long long scaled_average = arraysum(A, sum, i, n);
best = element 0
for (each element in the array [1...n-1])
  if (|n*A[i] - scaled_average| < |n*A[best] - scaled_average|) 
    best = i
```

Consider using `long long` for `sum` to avoid overflow.

---

Code simplification: no need to pass in `sum`.

```
long long arraysum(int A[], int i, int n) {
    long long sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        sum+=A[i];
    return sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to move the declaration of `A[100];` from here

```
int n, A[100], i, b, sum;
```

To just after the `scanf()` statement, to create a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```
    int n, i, b, sum;
    ...
    printf("Enter number of elements in array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int A[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         scanf("%d", &A[i]);
```

...creating an array just the right size for the need.

Once the array is populated, loop through it and use comparison operators to find the closest to the difference of *array values* and *average*.  (pseudo code:  `fabs(a[i]-ave) < fabs(a[i+1]-ave)`) tracking the array index of the array values closest.

Example:

```
average = arraysum(A, sum, i, n)/(n*(1.0));//divide by floating point

 int closestIndex;
 findClosest(int A, 100, average, &closestIndex);
 printf("Index of value closest to %f is %d\nClosest value is: %d\n",  
            average, closestIndex, A[closestIndex]);
```

Where `findClosest()` is defined:

```
void findClosest(int A[], size_t size, double ave int *index)
{
     int smallestIndex;
     for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
     {
          smallestIndex = fabs((double)A[i]-ave) < fabs((double)A[i+1]-ave) ? i : i + 1;
     }
     *index = smallestIndex 
}
```